# select only last li in first ul with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to select only last li in first ul with jquery (without class and id). Not li in inner ul. How?

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li>
<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ul>
</li>
**<li></li>**
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('ul').first().children('li').last()`..

Comment: `$('ul:first-child li:last-child')` or `$('ul:first li:last')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var li = $('ul').first().children('li').last();
```

Comment: @sudhar This is the difference between this answer and yours **Yours :** http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/acNRb/1/ **Current Answer :** http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/acNRb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('ul:eq(0) li:last-child')
```

Comment: will fail if the ul has no direct li's but only grand li's.. (_not possible but just saying_)

Comment: @Mr_Green if ul doesn't have direct li, then it isn't called a ul

Answer (score 0):

Use below.Give your ul a id

```
$('#yourulid li:last-child').val();
```